# Getting variable with THIS and placing it in localstorage on click event Not working

Tags: jquery, cordova, local-storage

I have a listview that loops out a list with each. It fetches from a database on a remote server. It works fine, but I want to based on the click let the user go to another page, and I need the id of the thing they clicked on to follow to that page with local storage.

So I coded this:

Getting variable with THIS and placing it in localstorage on click event Not working.

```
var ss = "http://localhost/arenaapp/services/";

var arenas;

$('#ListArenasPage').on('pageshow', function(event) {
        getarenaList();
});

function getarenaList() {
    var country = window.localStorage.getItem("country");
    $.getJSON(ss + 'getarenas.php?id=' + country, function(data) {
        $('#arenaList li').remove();
        arenas = data.items;
        $.each(arenas, function(index, arena) {
            $('#arenaList').append('<li><a href="">' +
                    '<img src="pics/' + arena.picture + '"/>' +
                    '<h4>' + arena.arenaName + '</h4>' + '<p id="category">Club:' + arena.arenaClub + '</p>' +
                    '<p>Capacity:' + arena.arenaCapacity + '</p>' +
                    '<span class="ui-li-count">' + arena.id + '</span></a></li>');
        });
        $('#arenaList').listview('refresh');
    });
}


$('#arenaList').on ('click', function(){
        window.localStorage.setItem("currentid", arena.id);
        document.location.href = "arenaDetails.html";
    });
```

I know there's a lot of problem with this. I can't set the Item because arena.id is not set. It's only set within the function I guess? But how can I make it so that the arena.id ends up in the localstorage item (the last block of my code). Guess I have to use THIS or something like that. But I'm new to jquery, how would you make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this -

```
$('#arenaList').on('click','li', function(){
   window.localStorage.setItem("currentid", $(this).find('.ui-li-count').text());
   document.location.href = "arenaDetails.html";
});
```

Comment: The errors went away about id being undefined. But now it seems that the event doesn't fire. I tried a console.log first line in the function, and it didn't fire.

Comment: Oh you updated your code? or I did something very wrong. It works now at least. Thanks a lot!!